# Clearing a combo box in vb 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, combobox, refresh

How can you clear or refresh a combo box in visual basic 2008 if the drop down style of the combo box is "dropwdownlist"? I can refresh the combo box if the style is "dropdown" but when i changed it to "dropdownlist" i can't clear it anymore/

This is the code that im using to clear the text.

```
End With
    With cmbItemType
        cmbItemType.ResetText()
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `selectedindex` to -1

In your case, it should be `cmbItemType.SelectedIndex = -1`